# Jdialog not getting focused in IE9

Tags: java, swing, internet-explorer-9

I am calling 2 jDialog back to back from a applet. As soon as I select the option from the first dialog and click OK button, the applet window get focused and the second dialog box lost the focus.

The problem occurs only in the IEand works fine in firefox and chrome. Please the code snippet. (though the actual problem in my full code occurs only in IE9, i am not sure why this is not working in IE8 in the SSCCE)

```
public class SampleApplet extends Applet{

protected JButton countryButton = new JButton("Select");

public synchronized void init()
{
    this.setBounds(new Rectangle(350,350));
    this.add(countryButton);


    countryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            getCountries();
            getCountries();             
        }

    });
}

protected void getCountries() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    JComboBox CountriesCombo = new JComboBox();
    CountriesCombo.addItem("India");
    CountriesCombo.addItem("Japan");
    panel.add(CountriesCombo, gbc);

    JOptionPane     optionPane  = new JOptionPane(panel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    final JDialog   dialog      = optionPane.createDialog(panel, "Select Countries");
    dialog.setModal(true);

    dialog.addWindowListener ( new WindowAdapter ()
    {
        public void windowOpened ( WindowEvent e )
        {
            dialog.requestFocus ();
        }
    });
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <applet code="SampleApplet.class" width="350" height="350">
    </applet>
```

Can I get some help on this.

Comment: Then I guess you need to show some nicely build [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I have the SSCCE ready, how to share it

Comment: Please do edit your question, with your SSCCE, that's it, replace previous code with this new one.

Comment: Give me some time, in the mean time, let me tell you something that you are drastically doing wrong. You are mixing `Swing` with `AWT`, which is never considered good in any sense :(

Comment: Actually on my side it's working as expected, Both the `JDialog`s are getting focus, without reverting the focus to the `Main Application`. My version of IE 9 is `9.0.8112.16421 (Updated Version : 9.0.5 (KB2647516))`, hopefully mine is the same version as yours !!

Comment: I forgot, I did changed `extends Applet` to `extends JApplet` though.

Comment: My version of IE is also 9.0.8112.16421 same as yours. I also extend to JApplet and its not working for me. Is there anything to go with the IE settings. Also can you explain what is actually wrong about combining SWING and AWT

Comment: What is your updated version, like mine is 9.0.5 (KB2674516)? Swing is an advancement over AWT, that's why never to mix them up.

Comment: yes the updated version is also same

Comment: Just a small suggestion, instead of providing `panel` as the parent to the `JDialog` try to give `JApplet` as the parent to the `JDialog`

Comment: You are MOST Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)  Glad you made it through the obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this behavior depends on browser you are running applet in (and seems you have proved it), so i'd offer you to try calling requestFocus() and requestFocusInWindow() on the dialog (or component inside it) to take the focus into the dialog box.

Once more - if you request focus BEFORE opening the dialog (before setVisible(true)) ofcourse it will fail since the dialog is not shown yet. If you call it AFTER the setVisible(true) method - if your dialog (or OptionPane) is modal - it will execute only when dialog is closed so it is meaningless there aswell. You should add a WindowListener to your dialog and request focus into the dialog after it is opened.

Check this example:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    // Modal dialog
    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog (  );
    dialog.setModal ( true );

    // Adding listener
    dialog.addWindowListener ( new WindowAdapter ()
    {
        public void windowOpened ( WindowEvent e )
        {
            dialog.requestFocus ();
        }
    } );

    // Displaying dialog
    dialog.setVisible ( true );
}
```

Still, dialog.requestFocus () here is a platform-dependant call which might not focus/pop your dialog atop of other opened windows. In all Windows versions it should work fine.

Also you can try using dialog.toFront () - this should pop the dialog and transfer focus into it.

Comment: I have already tried calling "requestFocus()" after the setVisible method on the dialog object. Do we need to call both  requestFocus() and requestFocusInWindow().

Comment: Call the latter, ***rather than*** the former, just like the compiler warnings urge you to do.

Comment: If the dialog is modal and you are calling those methods after setVisible be aware that it won't work since this method will return only after modal dialog is closed. To be sure that dialog takes focus you need to call requestFocus(). Though it might work different on various OS.

Comment: I have tried calling both methods before and after the setVisible() method, on the panel, optionPane, dialog and the rateCombo (component in the dialog). but the applet is getting focused. Also i have checked the requestFocusInWindow() method returns false in all these case. Can some give a code snippet for this, which will be helpful.

Comment: Check the updated post - i added some more description. And by the way - did you properly specify dialog parent?

Comment: I have tried with the code updated in post, but its still not working and I got the following trace.Entering Open
Exit Open
Entering Open
Exit Open

Comment: Also you have mentioned "did you properly specify dialog parent?" the dialog parent os jOptionPane and its is declared as follows         JOptionPane     optionPane  = new JOptionPane(panel, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

Comment: In this case please update your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (full working example of the code that reproduces the problem). Guessing what could the problem be is not the best way to solve it quickly.

Comment: Just edit your question and replace the code presented there - that simple :)